# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' - form tag and onclick

Tags: forms, onclick

I am a newbie to javascript and am following an old tutorial from 2013 in German.
I wonder if certain commands and codes are now deprecated as I have tried to make this code work in an external javascript file.

```
function clicked() {
alert("can't you read?");
}

<form>  
<input onclick="clicked()" type ="button" value = "don't click"/> 
      </form>
```

I get an error message which states:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

I get the same error message when I try this code instead,

```
<button onclick="clicked()" type="button">"don't click"</button>
```

I tried to find solutions online, but it appears as if the javascript-verse has evolved to more complicated looking solutions. 
Can someone help?
Thanks,
"

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out by finding a reference from 2008.
Anything between the form tags and including the form tags goes into the html file.

```
<form>  
<input onclick="clicked()" type ="button" value = "don't click"/> 
      </form>
```

The function itself remains on the external javascript file

```
function clicked() {
alert("can't you read?");
}
```

The solution looks definitely simpler than all other onsubmit or onclick codes I have seen today. I therefore assume that I may miss some tricks by being overly simplistic.